# Execute anothe file in behind after execution of php code

Tags: php, tree

Actually i have developed a tree structure when traversing it takes to much times on each addition of node. so i want to execute my code something like that

1- some code execution
2- a another file execution with a parameter passing to it ( this file should run behind this script like corn jobs)
3- code of redirection to another page

means that it should execute 1st step and 3rd step and as 2nd step take to much time it can execute on server and user will not have to wait.

i know it can something to do with corn job or something like that. i have tried the php exec function it executes the code but it also wait until its execution is complete all i wanted to make my execution on all nodes either faster or hide from user so that he/she will not have to wait

Comment: Why not use ajax to get the results after the layout is fully loaded?

Comment: other file will respond late because of large no of nodes so user will have to wait again until ajax respond the code will also take the time

Comment: I understand that, but you can give the user feedback while it's processing in the background, other options would be coding your own daemon that processes data in the background then sends a signal somehow, but it will be too complicated.

Comment: nice i but the user says he wants fast execution actually as nodes increase time of execution is also increases there are currently ~1600 nodes an user claims it will be around 20 new nodes daily so time will increase day by day that's y i want :(

Comment: Well, I think your best bet would be to "compile" these nodes when they get uploaded then just display them later, so it will be only slow after the first time.

Comment: i suggest also that but they want to display the results immediately that is why i was thinking of something like that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36950/discussion-between-oneofone-and-daman-mokha)

Answer (score -1):

I think background running can help you. Put "**`&`**" in the end of your command:

```
exec("php somefile.php &");
```

Hope this help.